# iOS Swift : can't Retrieve current url loaded in UIwebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, xcode-6.2

i am working in webview application iOS swift :

problem i am facing is i want to get each url which webview displays :

upon urls i have to perform some if else checks . but i could not get the urls which webview loads.

webview is displaying fine results and loading urls upon clicking . i want to fetch all urls which webview navigates on..

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class seconVC: UIViewController {

    var toPass:String!
    var touser:String!
    var toPassing:String!



    @IBOutlet weak var webV: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var L_back: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var R_frwrd: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var domurl = toPass;

        var username = touser;

        var passwing = toPassing;



        var sendurl = stringA+username+"/"+passwing;

        //exchange login with auth/username/password
        println(sendurl);

        let url = NSURL (string: sendurl);


        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webV.userInteractionEnabled = true
        webV.loadRequest(requestObj);



    }

    @IBAction func L_back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if (webV.canGoBack){
            webV.goBack()
        }


    }

    @IBAction func R_frwrd(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if (webV.canGoForward){
            webV.goForward()
        }

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


    }



}
```

all i want is to get string of current url and navigation buttons for webview :please help ? i referred all the internet no solution is working in my case .

Comment: i want is to get string of current url  -- when u need this

Comment: after loading main url in webview user interacts with webview there i want to get the urls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of `UIWebViewDelegate` such as `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` or `webViewDidStartLoad` or `webViewDidFinishLoad` or `didFailLoadWithError` that help you to accomplish your goal. If you want to perform operation after view did finished then implement this delegate method

**Swift 3**

```
if let currentURL = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString{
         print(currentURL)
    }
```

as it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946988/2621857).

Comment: Do you set the delegate properly? I mean webV.delegate = self and confirm the protocol.

Comment: first it gives error on public identifier then after removing public error is gone and when run the code no urls are fetched

Comment: it worked setting up the delegate it started giving urls

Answer (score 5):

**option-1**

```
let currentURL = webV.request.URL.absoluteString
```

**option-2**

get URL in delegate method

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
    print(WebView.request?.mainDocumentURL)
}
```

**option-3**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
let currentURL = webView.request().URL()
print("\(currentURL.description)")
}
```

or use like

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
 let currentURL = webView.request?.URL
}
```

**option-4**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
let currentURL: = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.location.href")!
print("\(currentURL)")
}
```

**option-5**

```
func webView(webview: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
let currentURL = request.URL.absoluteString
print("\(currentURL)")
}
```

**option-6**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(WebVie: UIWebView) {
  let currentURL = WebVie.request.mainDocumentURL
   print("\(currentURL)")
}
```

Comment: :-( man none of them are working .. whats happening with it, there must be some way .?

Comment: thanx for the help man option 3 worked with delegate protocol

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define the delegate for WebView class. "WebView.delegate = self". Add this code beside one of the function above:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebView.delegate = self  }
```

and for exmaple:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if let currentURL = WebView.request?.url?.absoluteString{
        print(currentURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @ejderuby! Some people downvoted the solutions, just wanted to clarify that they have to define the delegate first, and then delegates would work. I edited my answer with more explanation.