# How can I get the URL from webView in swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview, swift3, nsurl

I have question, how can I fetch the url from the `webView`?
I perform the following code and I get the `nil`

Code I'm trying :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv2zJErQt84")!))
    if let text = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString{
         print(text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not getting url because `webView` has not finished the loading of that requested `URL`, you can get that `URL` in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method of `UIWebviewDelegate`. For that you need to set delegate of `webView` with your current `ViewController` and need to implement `UIWebviewDelegate`.

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Now you can get current loaded `URL` of `webView` in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if let text = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString{
         print(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: @HaiderAhmed Welcome mate :)

Comment: can i get the videoURL not webview url see this and help me if you know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 7):

For **swift 5** and **swift 4.2** use `let url = webView.url?.absoluteString` :-

First import WebKit :-

```
import WebKit
```

Then add protocol :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate
```

Then add delegate:-

```
    //MARK:- WKNavigationDelegate

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Strat to load")
    
    if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString{
        print("url = \(url)")
    }
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
   
    if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString{
        print("url = \(url)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **Swift 3** version, make sure you have added `UIWebViewDelegate` in your class dseclaration and set `webView.delegate = self` in `viewDidload()`:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

    let urlString = webView.request!.url!.absoluteString
    print("MY WEBVIEW URL: \(urlString)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

If you want to see which url is navigating for load then use this delegate method. **navigationAction** specifically show which page is navigating. it can be diff than **webview.url**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    super.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
    let request = navigationAction.request
}
```